# change the secure password character in UITextfield

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextfield

Is it possible to change the secure password character displayed ?

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531274/how-do-i-stop-uitextfield-secure-text-showing-characters/29944670#29944670

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming Bobby B is right in that it is impossible to change the secret character,
I hereby present,
with no guarantuee whatsoever and with all warnings that are applicable,
since this is a **horrible kludge** which will certainly give you headaches at some point,
hoping not to be downvoted too much for it:

```
/* don't ever use this PROOF OF CONCEPT CODE for production use */
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{   
    if ( self.backing == nil ) self.backing = @"";
    static BOOL pasting = false;

    if ( !pasting )
    {       
        self.backing = [self.backing stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        NSLog(@"backing: %@",self.backing);
        if ( [string length] == 0 ) return YES; // early bail out when just deleting chars

        NSString *sec = @"";
        for ( int i=0;i<[string length]; i++ ) sec = [sec stringByAppendingFormat:@"■"];

        pasting = true;
        [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:sec];
        [textField paste:self];

        return NO;  
    } else {
        pasting = false;
        return YES; 
    }       
}   
/* you have been warned */
```

Set your `UITextField`'s delegate to the class containing this function.

Just make sure you have `self.backing` which is a retained `NSString*`. The copy&paste kludge was needed to preserve cursor position.

I don't know anything about pasting, this was a wild guess and it works, but you do need to find out if this may lead to some problem in that respect. I tested a little and it didn't seem to give any problem.

Comment: It is very likely to fail for autocorrection and certain international keyboards (in particular, auto-correction doesn't seem to call textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:).

Comment: I think autocorrection for secure entry is a bad idea anyway ;-) and I think it does call `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`, IIRC from a project with pixel-width limited input.

Comment: thanks. Is that advised to change the characters ? is that violating the iphone UI guidelines ?

Comment: I don't think this violates anything; there is no private framework/api you're breaking into, and the user experience is 99% that of a normal secure entry. Things may look different if you were to replace it with another *text*, rather than a single char ;-) The outline of such an approach would normally be used to limit input to certain chars, or a certain format.

Comment: This works perfect, however, I would recommend anyone using this to remove the NSLog() call. Those logs are traceable in the device logs, so if a user enters his password it might be found in the device logs.

Answer (score 8):

You could also just change the font...

If you change the unicode character 'BULLET' (U+2022) you can customise the secret character.
There are a lot of free font editor out there.
I use this one http://www.cr8software.net/typex.html

To add custom fonts to your project, check out - [this link](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

It's quite easy

Then you don't have to code anything it just works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible, and I'm basing that on a lack of documentation found in the docs for [UITextInputTraits](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html) (specifically for [secureTextEntry](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/secureTextEntry)).

Could be wrong though - interested to hear if someone has done this before.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Simply, allow Secure property in IB or via program.