# How do I hide the textfield cursor on the iPhone when keyboard is active

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextfield

we are trying this for password settings,so that cursor should not be visible to user.

Comment: Why would you like to hide the cursor? You should hide the characters, which is done by setting the secureTextEntry to YES, as @Peter has answered.

Comment: i need to hide(make invisible) the cursor from the user. its just advanced security i wanted to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting [the field's `secureTextEntry` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/secureTextEntry) to `YES`.

Comment: actually I want to hide the cursor(make it invisible) while editing the textfield....

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** to answer the question though, hiding the cursor is done easiest by overlaying the `UITextField` with another `UITextField`, where the back one is actually the first responder, and the front one acts to at least receive focus (using `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`, and passing focus on). In

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
                replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

apply the replacement on the front `UITextField` exactly, using something like

```
front.text = [front.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
```

You will probably break copy&paste functionality this way. Also, be very careful what you do in those delegate functions. Expect the unexpected.

My original answer, equally applicable:

---

I don't know what "advanced security" in this context would mean, but have a look at

[change the secure password character in uitextfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280069/change-the-secure-password-character-in-uitextfield/3280471)

To ruin the user experience even more, and maybe add more "security", you could:

- disable backspace functionality by returning `NO` if `[string length] == 0`
- add `1+(arc4rand()%4)` characters for every character entered (as seen on some windowing systems)
- add random characters instead of a constant placeholder character

but I must say that I *really* don't see the point of all this.

Comment: iPhone have PIN control where we can set password to lock phone, there also u don't find any cursor on textfield. We want to implement the same.

Comment: I know, and my answer gives a solution for that. Have you read it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dummy text field which is hidden and use the delegate textDidChage for TextField and use this value to fill the Masked Values in actual Password field.

In Interface Builder have a dummy textfield which is hidden, maintain a IBOutlet for that say

IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
IBOutlet UItextField *dummyField;

Also set delegate for this and write the following delegate methods

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
NSString *dummyText = dummyField.text;
NSString *changedText = @"";
if(dummyField == textField)
{
    if([string length] == 0)
    {
        if([dummyText length] <= 1)
        {
            changedText = @"";
        }
        else
        {
            changedText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dummyText substringToIndex:[dummyText length] - 1]]; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        changedText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",dummyText,string];
    }
    passwordField.text = changedText;
}
return YES; }

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
if(passwordField == textField)
{
    [dummyField becomeFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
return YES; }


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.I used the solution described 
[here](http://www.pietrorea.com/2012/07/how-to-hide-the-cursor-in-a-uitextfield/)

It replaces the UITextField with a custom UILabel with the following adjustments:

1. Override the properties inputView and inputViewAccessory to allow setting the keyboard view to appear when the label becomes the first responder.
  ```
      @interface PRLabel : UILabel     

      @property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UIView* inputView;
      @property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UIView* inputAccessoryView;

      @end
  ```
2. To make the label respond to touch events, override the method isUserInteractionEnabled to always return YES. Also, override the method touchesEnded to make the label the first responder when a touch is detected.
3. Override the method canBecomeFirstResponder to always return YES. This will allow the input view to come up.
  ```
      @implementation PRLabel
      -(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
      {
      self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
      if (self) {
      // Initialization code
      }
      return self;
      }

      -(BOOL)isUserInteractionEnabled
      {
      return YES;
      }

      -(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
      {
      return YES;
      }

      -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
      {
      [self becomeFirstResponder];
      }
      @end
  ```