# Secure UITextField text change to (*) asterisk character

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

How can I change a secure `UITextField` text (which is simply a bunch of dots) to (*) asterisk characters like in the image below?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [change the secure password character in UITextfield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280069/change-the-secure-password-character-in-uitextfield)

Answer (score 8):

You can set it programmatically by

```
[textField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
```

or in IB (secured checkbox at the bottom)

[image]

Comment: Yes but the text appears as dots.. I want asterisk

Comment: @TimTuffley I was so eager to answer that I didn't read it properly. Sorry for that.

Comment: @TimTuffley This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3280471/767730) might be useful.

Comment: Use the platform standard, which is dots. Why put the effort into customizing something so trivial just to make it not match every other app on the platform?

Comment: @JonShier Because there may be a comp that specifically wants asterisks instead of the default dots. Downvoting the answer because it does not solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try simply implementing your own "secure text field".

Simply create a normal, non-secure text field, and link it's "Editing Changed" action with a method in your view controller.

Then within that method you can take the new characters every time the text is changed, and add them to a private NSString property, and then set the textField's .text property to a string with just asterisks in it (or any other character if you prefer).

**Update:** as noted by *hayesk* below, this solution is no longer ideal, as the introduction of third-party keyboards exposes input on any non-secure text fields to the third-party application, risking them collecting that information, and/or adding it to the autocorrect database.

Comment: These solutions are bad because the field isn't really secure. It allows third party keyboards that can snoop and it may still add passwords to the autocorrect database.

Comment: Ahh, interesting. I wrote this answer before the existence of third-party keyboards, so that wasn't an issue at the time, but it's good to know that this is now no longer an ideal solution. Thanks!

Comment: You can add this code `func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplicationExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {
        if extensionPointIdentifier == .keyboard {
            return false
        }
        
        return true
    }` to your `AppDelegate` to disable third party keyboards.