# iOS 10 XCode 8 - secure text field, bug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I updated my app from Xcode 7 to Xcode 8 and now I am facing a problem with my password input field.
When the password is longer than the provided field, my app freezes and starts to consume memory until it crashes.
Fun fact, it just happens when I set the text to "secure text".
My field is vertically centered and has a fixed width (not sure if thats imporant), 
and when my password is longer than the number of characters, the input field can take (and where it should move to the left) I get the crash.

Did anybody experience smt like that?
(as I said I just updated to a newer XCode - running on a 10.0.2 real device, didnt have that problem on the old one ...)

Thanks,

Regards

Comment: Are you facing this issue in all devices or only on certain devices like iPhone 5s 6 etc.,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is a bug.

Bug is like :

> An app can freeze when a user types a large password into a textfield that tries to scale down the text to fit.

Check it : https://openradar.appspot.com/28590124

Possible solution :

1. [change the secure password character in UITextfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280069/change-the-secure-password-character-in-uitextfield/3280471#3280471)
2. [Secure UITextField text change to (*) asterisk character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006499/secure-uitextfield-text-change-to-asterisk-character?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The quote is from the reporter, not from Apple.

Comment: Thanks, thanh, i modified it.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to deal with it on my own and not wait for Apple to fix it

Comment: Thanks for this, I thought I was crazy. If you aren’t set on keeping font scaling for long passwords, another workaround is unchecking “Adjust to Fit” in the “Min Font Size” section in that UITextField’s attribute inspector. The password will appear truncated when you're done editing.