# Secure text entry freezes when I try to type one character

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a password text field which will crash the app if I try to type a single character. I have referenced [this](https://openradar.appspot.com/28590124) but still no luck. I am running iOS 11.2.6 Here are my configs [image]

Comment: Add your crash log

Comment: There is no crash error, it just says `Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue`. That happens ~30 sec after clicking on the keyboard. Then is just freezes, doesn't crash.

Comment: Are testing it on device or simulator?

Comment: On an actual device.

Comment: seems like the problem is elsewhere, not the textfield, do you have any array that contains image or something?

Comment: When I disable secure text entry the issue goes away.

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950971/ios-10-xcode-8-secure-text-field-bug

Answer (score 0):

I just found out, if you are using Custom Class for UITextField, setting self.textColor in that class on Secure Text Entry text field might be the cause of freezing. I solved it by doing:

```
if (!self.isSecureTextEntry) {
    self.textColor = UIColor.white
}
```