# How do I stop UITextField Secure text showing characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I've enabled Secure text for my UITextField. At runtime when I type some text in I initially see the character before it turns to a bullet point. Is there a way to stop it showing the characters and having it as a bullet point as I type.

Is there something I need to add to

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Has anyone got an example?

Comment: thats the default behaviour

Comment: On mobile screen there is a limited space for keys. So, if they put bullet directly on key press like desktop system, you cant be sure if you have added correct character. So, for mobile this is a common behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That is the default behaviour of the `UITextField`.** So there's nothing much you can do about it. You can play with some kind of encryption on the coding side but on the view side, this behaviour will prevail.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know its good practice or not but following trick did it for me

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *editedString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    textField.text = editedString;
    return NO;
}
```